# Hibernate Criteria, Joins, Or

Tags: java, hibernate, join, restriction

I'm trying to accomplish ad-hoc queries using joined tables, using an Restrictions.or and Restrictions.ilike

My entities look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CASE_REVIEW")
public class CaseReview {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "REVIEW_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 19)
    private Long reviewId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CASE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Case reviewCase;

 }

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "CASE")
 public class Case {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 19)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne( fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinColumn( name="STUDENT_ID" , referencedColumnName="ID", 
    private StudentInformation studentInformation;

 }

 @Entity
 @Table( name="STUDENT")
 public class StudentInformation {
    @Id
    @Column( name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column( name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column( name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
 }
```

My code does something like the following:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria( CaseReview.class );
c.createAlias( "reviewCase" , "reviewCase"); 
c.createAlias( "reviewCase.studentInformation" , "reviewCasestudentInformation");
c.add( Restrictions.or( Restrictions.ilike("reviewCasestudentInformation.lastName" , "%e%" ), Restrictions.ilike( "reviewCasestudentInformation.firstName" , "%e" )));
```

I'm getting org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: reviewCasestudentInformation of: CaseReview.  I've also tried creating multi-tier aliases:

```
c.createAlias( "reviewCase.studentInformation" , "reviewCaseStudentInformation");
```

and using that in the restriction.or with the same results.  Strangely enough either set of aliases  work fine for

```
Order.asc( "reviewCaseStudentInformation.lastName")
```

Pretty much at a loss.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another criteria — ie a subcriteria — like this:

```
Criteria criteraCaseReview = session.createCriteria(CaseReview.class);
Criteria criteraReviewCase = criteraCaseReview.createCriteria("reviewCase");
criteraReviewCase.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ilike("lastName", "%e%"), Restrictions.ilike( "firstName", "%e")));
```

PS. I reckon it doesn't help that `ReviewCase` is a field on `CaseReview`... it makes the code rather confusing!